# How to add Tooltip Functionality to X-axis labels in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how can show Tooltip on formatted X-Axis label. This tooltip must contain un-formatted text. 
Refer this sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeHyB/2/) which depicts the same scenario.

```
labels:{
                formatter: function(){
                    if (this.value.length > 10){
                        return this.value.substr(0,10) + "...";
                    }else{
                         return this.value;   
                    }                        
                }
            }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: what does it mean  'un-formatted' text?? what you want to display?

Comment: @SRK  I've replace long label with "label....", so on hover it should show me the un-formated one i.e. "label with long text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts by default does not support tooltip for x-axis's labels. You may try [this](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin that allows you to add events(click, dbclick) on label. Just add a mouseover event and display a custom tooltip.

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gW4p6/235/). I'm getting the tooltip, but need to show substring of an X-axis label.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, so simple :)